# Delete Broadcast receive SMS in my inbox programmatically

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to develop a project. 
Upon receipt of an SMS broadcast I call abortBroadcast() method that deletes the message in my inbox automatically. 
With Android 2.1, 2.3 always works well but Android 4.4 SMS does not disappear in the inbox. 
I use:

```
Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, "address=?", new String[] {number});
```

but nothing

Someone make me a proposal?

Comment: What you want is not possible on Android 4.4+: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: ok thanks for your answer. I'll see how I do. for Android 4 ... is the top. or who can do more can do less

Comment: @CommonsWare is it possible after making app as Default SMS app? just curious

Comment: @Amritesh: I am not certain what "it" is. If "it" is "not store the SMS" then AFAIK the default SMS app can do that. After all, the default SMS app has the ability to delete messages upon user request.

Answer (score 0):

According to [android-developers.blogspot.com](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) you can't do that on Android 4.4. However, only the app that is chosen by user as default SMS app is able to write to the SMS Provider